# Large hadron collider

Tags: black-hole, universe, cosmology

Whether the collision of particle will lead to a massive WORMHOLE or if BLACKHOLE is also possible? How much I know is that it's created for einstien's E=mc^2 ,conservation of energy from mass and speed of light. I guess also for the STRING THEORY.

Comment: Others have said this, but to add, there's nothing that happens in CERN that doesn't happen in the outer Earth's atmosphere when very near light speed cosmic rays hit the Earth.   More powerful collisions happen on the edge of Earth than in CERN every few minutes, some of them, much much more powerful, like the oh my god particle (worth looking up).   "Recreating the moments after the big bang" happens all the time.   What makes CERN special, is they have four 70 foot camera lenses taking pictures at precisely the moment of impact. The energy of the impact isn't new, the ability to film it is.

Comment: Voting to close as this seems like it belong on the Physics SE, not astronomy.

Comment: How much science fiction went into the creation of this question? Please research some of the things you've mentioned before you ask about them!

Comment: Sorry but now I know that blackholes are not at all possible but can you tell me whether it can prove string theory ?

Answer (score 4):

Even if the LHC did create a black hole, its mass would be no greater than the sum of the particles that formed it, i.e. very tiny. It would evaporate almost instantly due to Hawking radiation. Secondly, subatomic particles have been colliding with atoms high in earth's atmosphere for eons, and we're still here.

Comment: Thanks but what about the wormhole?

Comment: @user315866 Wormholes are probably impossible and if they are possible, they're even less likely to create than micro black holes and at cern energies, would be very small, smaller than an atom.   Numerous other threads on Wormholes, one here:  http://phys.org/news/2015-03-mini-black-holes-lhc-parallel.html

Answer (score 3):

The LHC has a maximum collision energy of 13 TeV. This yields in mass of $m = E / c^2 = 13 ~\mathrm{TeV} / (3 \times 10^8 \frac{\mathrm{m}}{\mathrm{s}})^2 \approx 2.3 \times 10 ^{-23} ~\mathrm{kg}$.
Using the definition of the Schwarzschildradius $r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2}$, our black hole would have the size of $r_s \approx 3.4 \times 10^{-50} m$
It would be pretty small (and irrelevant)

Comment: Planck Length is $1.6 \times 10^{-35} m$ meaning the black hole wouldn't exist because it would need to be much smaller than the smallest possible quantum of reality.

Comment: There was some thought that if additional dimensions existed a micro black hole would be possible.   Probably wasn't a largely accepted theory, but it was proposed as possible.   http://phys.org/news/2015-03-mini-black-holes-lhc-parallel.html    The black holes not showing up in the collisions was pretty much the end of that theory I think.